# Create a Morris Line graph with a dynamic data

Tags: jquery, arrays, morris.js, linegraph

I need to create a Line Graph that shows total number of orders per store in a day, week or month.

Per month return data:

```
January, Store1, 80
January, Store2, 90
January, Store3, 50
February, Store1, 80
February, Store2, 90
February, Store3, 50
March, Store1, 80
March, Store2, 90
March, Store3, 50
```

And Store name is dynamic.

Need to create a line graph with

```
xkey:month(January-December)

ykeys:['store1 value','store2 value','store2 value']

labels: ['store1','store2','store2']` -> dynamic stores depends on the merchant
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `.setData()` when you have a new dataset to display.